# Change value on specific column when condition is met on another column

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I need help regarding the screenshot above. If possible I want a vba code that starts checking in F2 cell in row F(Unit Price) and change the adjacent values of row H and I to "01/01/2010" if the value on unit price is 0 and loop until an empty cell. Thanks in advance.

```
Range("F1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AI$9036").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
Range("H3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1/1/2010"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H3:I3"), Type:=xlFillCopy
Range("H3:I3").Select
Selection.FillDown
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AI$9036").AutoFilter Field:=6
```

Tried this one but the value doesnt change

```
 Sub test()
 irow = 2
 Do
 If (Sheets("Prices").Cells(6, 1).Value = 0) Then Cells(8, 1).Value = "01/01/2010"
 irow = irow + 1
 Loop Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Prices").Cells(irow, 6))
 End Sub
```

Comment: I tried getting the specific cell value for row F and change it to 01/01/2010 however it changes it all

Comment: @pnuts thank you so much. I am complicating things forgot that I can just filter it and record it as macro

Comment: If range is not large then as suggested by @pnuts filter column F for criteria and paste the desired value ie "01/01/2010" in range H:I to visible cells only. Macro may not be necessary.

Comment: i tried the code above but it doesnt work when the range is around 50000 rows

Comment: please see tried codes above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works in less than 1 sec with 100,000 rows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub updateDates()

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
        .Columns(8).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) = "1/1/2010"
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 To 100000
    With Sheets("Prices")
        If .Range("F" & i).Value = "0" Then _
        .Range("H" & i).Value = "01/01/2010"
    End With
Next i
```

This one worked